# Can you include condition-checking code in a format string?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a custom control which is part of a list. The text that it should display is set by assigning a value to its Text property. At runtime, this text is loaded from a database. I want to prepend this text with the string "Toelichting: " (Dutch for "Explanation"). I can accomplish this by setting the FormatString property of the control to the following:

```
"Toelichting: {0}"
```

Now, if the text that is loaded is an empty string, I want to display "Toelichting: –", so with an en-dash at the end. Otherwise, I want to display "Toelichting: MyText". Is it possible to add some condition-checking code to the FormatString, such that I can check if the parameter is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the most concise and correct answer to my questions. The other suggestions would be nice workarounds, but unfortunately they are no option for me.

Comment: If you had the option to bind to a type other than string, then you could override the ToString() method on that type to do what you wanted. If you can wrap your string in such a type, that would work.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just this?

```
string.Format("Toelichting: {0}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(explanation) ? "–" : explanation);
```

I don't think there's a way to embed this within the format string.

Comment: I cannot do this, because I have no control over the actual assignment of the text to the control, as it is part of a more complex, composite control. That is why I tried to embed this logic in the FormatString.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I'm afraid you'd need to replace an empty string with an en-dash as you retrieve the data. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
String.Format("Toelichting: {0}", 
    (String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourstr)) ? "-" : yourstr);
```

Not perfect but its relatively compact and readable.

Comment: I cannot do this, because I have no control over the actual assignment of the text to the control, as it is part of a more complex, composite control. That is why I tried to embed this logic in the FormatString.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this sort of thing a lot then consider writing your own formatter so that you could write code like this...

foo = string.Format(new MyFormatter(), "Toelichting: {0:explanation}", bar);

MyFormatter would implement IFormatProvider and ICustomFormatter.

Check out this...

[.NET: Is there a String.Format form for inserting the value of an object property into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357447/-net-is-there-a-string-format-form-for-inserting-the-value-of-an-object-property)

... which is probably more complicated than you need (as it deals with reflection and works with any object)